# How to make RGB code in xcode same as RGB in photoshop[WindowsOS]?

Tags: windows, macos, photoshop, color-picker

When i pick RGB color from photoshop on window os its give different than what pick from macos

Comment: ask for recommendation of tools is off-topic here.

Comment: now is it ok?
I am facing problem of RGB code. that is difference in window photoshop and xcode

Comment: So if you pick RGB(150,90,30) in Windows do you get 150,90,30 or not? What about OS X? If you pick RGB(150,90,30) there do you get 150,90,30 or not?

Comment: The RGB is actually the same. Each computer has different color profile, try to set to same color profile. You'd probably need to calibrate the monitor as well.

Comment: What, please give more information. What you're saying is impossible.

Comment: @Schemetrical

I am picking color RGB from photoshop in windows with color profile sRGB IEC61966-2.1. Its Result is 63-200-170.
But when my programmer picking color RGB from default colorpicker  in MacOS with color profile sRGB IEC61966-2.1. Its Result is 56-201-171.
I need same result with all OS or any color picker can you please let me know how is it possible?

Comment: In short i want same result for RGB color picking from any OS or PC. How is it possible?

Comment: @Nilesh because Photoshop attempts to present the color closely as possible by modifying the displayed colors to conform to the color profile. The default colorpicker will pick the displayed color (that was adjusted by photoshop), not the actual raw color.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off colour management in Photoshop for the PSD you have provided to your programmer:

Edit -> Assign Profile -> Don't Color Manage This Document

That way, the RGB values will be the actual RGB values without compensation for color profile.